# Find list of special folders in Windows using Qt

Tags: qt, windows-7, operating-system

Is it possible to get a list of the Special Folders in Windows 7 using Qt 4.7.4
I need to know in which directory the Operating System is installed and which folders I have write- access to.
Special Folders will include folders like 'Desktop', 'Program Data', etc....
These folders may or may not be hidden.

I appreciate your time and response.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

A few options:

- Qt already has paths to many of these (cross-platform) in **QDesktopServices**. The method is `QDesktopServices::storageLocation(StandardLocation)`.
- For some, you can use **qgetenv** (as mentioned above).
- If all else fails, you can directly call the **SHGetSpecialFolderPath** method in the Shell32 library. The list of possible options can be found on [Microsoft's site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762494%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Here is a sample of the last:

```
static QString getWindowsPath(int path_to_get)
{
    typedef BOOL (WINAPI*GetSpecialFolderPath)(HWND, LPWSTR, int, BOOL);

    QLibrary shell32_lib(QLatin1String("shell32"));
    GetSpecialFolderPath SHGetSpecialFolderPath =
        (GetSpecialFolderPath)shell32_lib.resolve("SHGetSpecialFolderPathW");

    QScopedPointer<wchar_t> w_path(new wchar_t[MAX_PATH]);
    SHGetSpecialFolderPath(0, w_path.data(), path_to_get, FALSE);

    return QString::fromWCharArray(w_path.data());
}
```

(Actually, `SHGetSpecialFolderPath` has been superseded by [SHGetKnownFolderPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762188%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) as of Vista, so if you know you are only targeting Windows 7, you should use that instead. It uses a [KNOWNFOLDERID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd378457%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) value.)

Comment: In Qt 5, the methods to get special folders have been moved from `QDesktopServices` to [`QStandardPaths`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qstandardpaths.html).

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [getenv](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/tehxacec%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) from stdlib.

For example: You can find the path where the OS is installed under the environment variable `windir`.

Other examples:

- APPDATA
- COMPUTERNAME
- PROGRAMFILES

You can find more examples [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable#Default_Values_on_Microsoft_Windows)

Code example:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cassert>

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    char* programs_path = getenv("programfiles");

    assert( programs_path );

    return 0;
}
```

Remember to check if `getenv` returned null, especially for environment variables which you set yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [QtGlobal::qgetenv](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qtglobal.html#qgetenv). It get the environment variables, and [here](http://www.binbert.com/blog/2010/09/default-environment-variable-values-of-windows-7-xp/) is the list of variables available on windows 7.