# QT auto start application on Windows

Tags: qt

Im trying to get my application to start one the user logs on to his or hers account.

My current code:

```
#ifdef Q_OS_WIN
QSettings bootUpSettings("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\Wow6432Node\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", QSettings::NativeFormat);
QString base_dir = qApp->applicationDirPath() + "\\MyApp.exe";

if (autoStartChecked == "true") {
    bootUpSettings.setValue("MyApp","\""+base_dir+"\"");
} else {
    bootUpSettings.remove("MyApp");
}
#endif
```

When I look in regedit I can see that my application has added the key with value, but for some reason the application wont auto start when i logon to Windows.

Any ideas?

Comment: not sure you need to quote the path, the reg setting is already a string and does not needs to be escaped...

Comment: this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9534415/run-application-on-startup/ and my answer

Answer (score 3):

You have to put the path to your application executable into the

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run

key instead. I.e.:

```
QSettings bootUpSettings("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", QSettings::NativeFormat);
QString app_path = QCoreApplication::applicationFilePath();
if (autoStartChecked == "true") {
    bootUpSettings.setValue("MyApp", app_path);
} else {
    bootUpSettings.remove("MyApp");
}
```

Comment: For some reason it wont add the key at that location (Im testing on Windows 7).. testing your update

Comment: @user3490755, what is the error? Can you diagnose it?

Comment: Just wont get added for some reason. How can i make QSettings return the error?

Comment: It doesn't work on Windows 10 because writing to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` requires administrator privileges, changing it to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` works fine.