# launch application automatically when you start your computer in C++

Tags: c++, windows-7, qt5

There is some one can tell me how to develop an application which launches automatically when you start the computer using C++/Qt.

Comment: There are three ways to start programs automatically, and only one involves programming. The ways are: [Add it to the "Startup" folder](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/run-program-automatically-windows-starts#1TC=windows-7); Add to a special key in the registry, don't remember which one exactly right now; The third way is to make your program a *service*.

Comment: You can refer to a related [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9534415/run-application-on-startup) on this topic

Comment: Thanks a lot these answers helped me very much.

Answer (score 1):

See this [description by Microsoft](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/run-program-automatically-windows-starts#1TC=windows-7). Just place a link to your application in the Autostart folder of Windows. You don't have to change anything in your application.

Comment: While links are appreciated, they should not be the sole content of your answer. Please summarize the relevant part.